# How to go to the specific position in ScrollPane?

Tags: javafx

By default my `ScrollPane` is in top left . Now i want to change it for example my `ScrollPane` start from 400 x 400 . Any ideas ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by putting the scrollpane into a pane and then use the relocate method. Example:

```
scrollPane.relocate( 400, 400);
```